# XSLT how to create output based on the values of different nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I have this (pseudo-code) xml

```
<data>
<ref>one</ref>
<val>20</val>
<ref>two</ref>
<val>200</val>
<ref>three</ref>
<val>2000</val>
</data>
```

Then, let's say that I don't know which values are in "val" nodes. Thus, I would like to have the xhtml output

-> IF there is any "val" below 100

```
<div class="low">values 20,200,2000 in one,two,three</div>
```

-> IF there is any "val" below 1000 but not below 100

```
<div class="medium">values 20,200,2000 in one,two,three</div>
```

-> IF there is any "val" below 10000 but not below 1000

```
<div class="high">values 20,200,2000 in one,two,three</div>
```

*In the last 2 cases, the initial values should be different

Any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by: "*In the last 2 cases, the initial values should be different" ? Please, explain -- what do you mean by "initial values" and what these should be?

Comment: So, following the stated requirements, all three `<div>` elements must be output? Is that right?

Comment: Just state that in the "medium" case, values should be for example 120, 200, 2000, and not the original 20, 200, 2000. And the same with the "high" case. Otherwise it will find always a value below 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get max valu in "1.0" XSLT version we need extension function. I have created it for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" exclude-result-prefixes="math">

  <xsl:param name="checkValue">
    <xsl:variable name="value" select="math:max(//val)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$value &lt; 100">
        <xsl:text>low</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$value &lt; 1000 and $value &gt; 100">
        <xsl:text>medium</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$value &lt; 10000 and $value &gt; 1000">
        <xsl:text>high</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <div class="{$checkValue}">
      <xsl:text>values </xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="val">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text> in </xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="val">
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ref[1]"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output:**

```
<div class="high">values 20, 200, 2000 in one, two, three</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic :) That's what I wanted to get